# PhantomJS webdriver can't load url

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, rpa

I use phantomjs webdriver for RPA implementation. There is one url that it tries to load with this code:

```
webDriver.get(url);
```

The thing is that I can go to this url manually (just copying it into my address line in browser). It loads fine. But when it comes to phantomjs, it can't load it. I thought that it may be related to ssl protocol, so set these options for phantomjs:

```
--ignore-ssl-errors=true
--ssl-protocol=any
--web-security=true
```

Still the same thing. In debug mode I got the following logs when trying to load the url:

```
[DEBUG] HTTP Request - URI /session/1ed10cc0-ddc6-11e8-87f5-2f782befb71d/url
[DEBUG] HTTP Request - Method POST
[DEBUG] HTTP Request - HTTP Version 1.1
[DEBUG] HTTP Request - Query String 
[DEBUG] HTTP Request - Receiving Header "Accept" = "application/json, image/png"
[DEBUG] HTTP Request - Receiving Header "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
[DEBUG] HTTP Request - Receiving Header "Content-Length" = "141"
[DEBUG] HTTP Request - Receiving Header "Host" = "localhost:64560"
[DEBUG] HTTP Request - Receiving Header "Connection" = "Keep-Alive"
[DEBUG] HTTP Request - Method POST/PUT
[DEBUG] HTTP Request - Content Body: {"url":"myHiddenUrl"}
[DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 56
[DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 58
[DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 61
[DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 63
[DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 66
[DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 69
[DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 72
[DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 74
[DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 77
[DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 80
[DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(OperationCanceledError) ( "Operation canceled" ) URL: "http://localhost:8080/idea/style/kendo/fonts/glyphs/WebComponentsIcons.ttf?gedxeo"
[DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100
[DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10
[DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
[DEBUG] HTTP Response - Status Code 500 Internal Server Error
[DEBUG] HTTP Response - Sending Header "Cache" = "no-cache"
[DEBUG] HTTP Response - Sending Header "Content-Length" = "54132"
[DEBUG] HTTP Response - Sending Header "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

So as you see there is 500 error. But I have no idea to what it may be related. I don't have such an issue manually. Can it be something with request headers?
Thanks in advance for any help with this issue.

Comment: error 500 is coming from the server. SO you should ask whoever is responsible for that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing some `POST` request parameters where your request seems to be invalid.

You are able to load the `URL` manually which narrows it down and supports the above statement.

Make sure the request information being sent is not missing anything.